# mod-pagespeed questions

Tags: apache-2.2

make lots error.log  like:

[error] [1125/151943:ERROR:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(674)] Poll success status 0 (111)

Answer (score 1):

You might one to check upon your ModPagespeedDomain settings.

it seems like that mod pagespeed has issues with domain aliases